# ggplot: How to show time series that significantly deviate from average

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I am making a system where we will plot progress of individual subjects across time. One measurement per week. I can easily plot the individual progress lines very thin and semi transparent plus a rather thick, overlying average line:

[image]

I get the average line by making a dataframe where observations are summarised by `mean()`:

```
df.avg.feeling <- df.lines.feeling %>%
  dplyr::group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(feeling=mean(feeling))
```

This works well with about 10, maybe 15 subjects. We can see that line `666666` is significantly different. However if I have 50 subjects it would be hard to discern individual lines. The aim of this graph is to catch those data series that significantly deviate from the average line. My question is - how can I make a dataframe where I select only those 10 data series/lines that most deviate from the average? I could plot then those lines only. I sort of see that some score of deviation from average line would need to be created so that I could select top *n* observation series. Is this right, and how to do this for timeseries lines/data?

Data are organised like this:

```
    date         id    feeling
1   2019-08-08  111111  68
2   2019-08-15  111111  45
3   2019-08-22  111111  60
4   2019-08-29  111111  70
5   2019-09-05  111111  55
...
102 2019-11-21  666666  70
103 2019-11-28  666666  68
```

Current dataframe with `dput()` is:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(18116, 18123, 18130, 18137, 
18144, 18151, 18158, 18116, 18123, 18130, 18137, 18144, 18151, 
18158, 18116, 18123, 18130, 18137, 18144, 18151, 18158, 18116, 
18123, 18130, 18137, 18144, 18151, 18158, 18116, 18123, 18130, 
18137, 18144, 18151, 18158, 18116, 18123, 18130, 18137, 18144, 
18151, 18158, 18116, 18123, 18130, 18137, 18144, 18151, 18158, 
18165, 18172, 18179, 18186, 18193, 18200, 18207, 18214, 18221, 
18228, 18235, 18165, 18172, 18179, 18186, 18193, 18200, 18207, 
18214, 18221, 18228, 18235, 18165, 18172, 18179, 18186, 18193, 
18200, 18207, 18214, 18221, 18228, 18235, 18165, 18172, 18179, 
18186, 18193, 18200, 18207, 18214, 18221, 18228, 18235, 18165, 
18172, 18179, 18186, 18193, 18200, 18207, 18214, 18221, 18228, 
18235, 18165, 18172, 18179, 18186, 18193, 18200, 18207, 18214, 
18221, 18228, 18235, 18165, 18172, 18179, 18186, 18193, 18200, 
18207, 18214, 18221, 18228, 18235, 18242, 18242, 18242, 18242, 
18242, 18242, 18243, 18243, 18243, 18243, 18243, 18243), class = "Date"), 
    id = c(111111L, 111111L, 111111L, 111111L, 111111L, 111111L, 
    111111L, 121212L, 121212L, 121212L, 121212L, 121212L, 121212L, 
    121212L, 111333L, 111333L, 111333L, 111333L, 111333L, 111333L, 
    111333L, 131313L, 131313L, 131313L, 131313L, 131313L, 131313L, 
    131313L, 444444L, 444444L, 444444L, 444444L, 444444L, 444444L, 
    444444L, 666666L, 666666L, 666666L, 666666L, 666666L, 666666L, 
    666666L, 777117L, 777117L, 777117L, 777117L, 777117L, 777117L, 
    777117L, 111111L, 111111L, 111111L, 111111L, 111111L, 111111L, 
    111111L, 111111L, 111111L, 111111L, 111111L, 121212L, 121212L, 
    121212L, 121212L, 121212L, 121212L, 121212L, 121212L, 121212L, 
    121212L, 121212L, 111333L, 111333L, 111333L, 111333L, 111333L, 
    111333L, 111333L, 111333L, 111333L, 111333L, 111333L, 131313L, 
    131313L, 131313L, 131313L, 131313L, 131313L, 131313L, 131313L, 
    131313L, 131313L, 131313L, 444444L, 444444L, 444444L, 444444L, 
    444444L, 444444L, 444444L, 444444L, 444444L, 444444L, 444444L, 
    666666L, 666666L, 666666L, 666666L, 666666L, 666666L, 666666L, 
    666666L, 666666L, 666666L, 666666L, 777117L, 777117L, 777117L, 
    777117L, 777117L, 777117L, 777117L, 777117L, 777117L, 777117L, 
    777117L, 111111L, 111111L, 111111L, 111111L, 121212L, 121212L, 
    121212L, 444444L, 131313L, 666666L, 777117L, 111111L), feeling = c(68L, 
    45L, 60L, 70L, 55L, 70L, 75L, 45L, 60L, 62L, 70L, 75L, 65L, 
    71L, 30L, 30L, 65L, 65L, 68L, 74L, 70L, 35L, 20L, 40L, 55L, 
    70L, 65L, 75L, 40L, 48L, 52L, 52L, 60L, 70L, 72L, 55L, 60L, 
    30L, 25L, 10L, 35L, 25L, 52L, 60L, 65L, 60L, 70L, 75L, 85L, 
    70L, 72L, 75L, 80L, 65L, 65L, 60L, 75L, 77L, 80L, 65L, 65L, 
    70L, 72L, 75L, 55L, 52L, 60L, 70L, 78L, 90L, 70L, 65L, 80L, 
    82L, 88L, 75L, 80L, 82L, 90L, 85L, 70L, 69L, 80L, 86L, 70L, 
    65L, 50L, 45L, 30L, 50L, 70L, 75L, 82L, 72L, 82L, 65L, 50L, 
    65L, 70L, 72L, 76L, 70L, 68L, 71L, 45L, 60L, 61L, 48L, 32L, 
    20L, 32L, 42L, 50L, 55L, 45L, 68L, 72L, 79L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
    69L, 72L, 75L, 78L, 81L, 77L, 70L, 67L, 69L, 85L, 72L, 67L, 
    17L, 62L, 74L, 4L, 24L)), row.names = c(NA, -138L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is not really a concrete programming question ("which line is most deviating") and feels kind of opinion based.

Comment: My initial thought would be to use subject ID as a predictor in a regression model for these data, then examine the saved regression parameters for your "top 10." Next, plot the data by color/factor that represents these individuals.

Comment: @Georgery I understand what you mean. Question is about how to estimate which lines most differ from the average. It is how to model the difference

Comment: Can you repost with more cases of your data?

Comment: That kind of strengthens my point. This feels opinion-based and therefore does not really belong here.

Comment: For the record: a simple thing you could do is to calculate the root mean squared of the difference between a group and the average over time, and there pick the x highest values.

Comment: @Georgery - what would be proto-code for that? I am sorry, I am just learning this stuff. You mean average of all measurements for 1 ID series across time compared with average of all average points over time?

Comment: Here is my "proto code"....sorry I don't have time to prepare something closer to wha tyou want...

`model1<-lm(feeling~date+id,data=df);
summary(model1$effects); # let's assume this variable is suitable for ranking what is plotted
df$effect<-model1$effects;
df$top10<-ifelse(df$effect>mean(df$effect),   # is case in upper quartile?
                "Highest Quartile","Lower");
aggr <- df %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(feeling=mean(feeling));
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=df,aes(date,feeling, group=id, color=top10)) +
    geom_line(data=aggr, aes(date,feeling),size=2,alpha=.5)`

Comment: Thank you @Ben, this gives me a good idea how to proceed.

Comment: Sure.  I'd be happy collaborate on posting a useful answer to this question later.